# Pass a function in another function and make a score counter

Tags: javascript

I am working on a coding task to coding a Rock, Paper, Scissors game.
I have written some functions already to handle to computer choice and user choice, and I'm also supposed to write a function to call the other functions and also keep track of the scores.

I am stuck without a way of bring everything together. This is my code below.

```js
let input;
let random;

function getComputerChoice(min = 1, max = 3){
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

    if (random === 1){
        console.log("computer picked Rock");
        return random;
    }
    else if (random === 2){
        console.log("computer picked Paper");
        return random;
    }
    else
        random === 3;
        console.log("computer picked Scissors");
        return random;

}


function playerSelection(){
    input = prompt("Input Rock, Paper or Scissors").toLowerCase();  
    console.log("you picked", input);
    return input;
} 


function playRound(yourSelection, computerSelection) {
    // your code here!
    
    if (yourSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === 3){
        console.log("you win")
    }
    else if (yourSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === 2){
        console.log("you win")
    }
    else if (yourSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === 1){
        console.log("you win")
    }
    else
        console.log("You lose, try again")
}
   
const yourSelection = playerSelection();
const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
playRound(yourSelection, computerSelection);

function game(){
    var theGame = game()
}
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You can simplify and allow for more choices if you do `const choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors", "Lizard", "Spock"]; const getComputerChoice = () => {  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);    console.log(`Computer picked ${choices[randomIndex]}`);
    return randomIndex + 1; /* to return 1-n instead of 0 to n-1 */}`

Comment: You should equip your `playRound()` function with a return value, indicating whether the user or the computer has got the point. This value can then be used in a "game" loop to update the user and the computer scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `game` function you'd need a loop to run a round and save the scores. If you want to end the game enter "exit".

```js
function getComputerChoice(min = 1, max = 3) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

  if (random === 1) {
    console.log("computer picked Rock");
    return random;
  } else if (random === 2) {
    console.log("computer picked Paper");
    return random;
  } else
    random === 3;
  console.log("computer picked Scissors");
  return random;
}

function playerSelection() {
  let input = prompt("Input Rock, Paper or Scissors or exit to end the game").toLowerCase();
  console.log("you picked", input);
  return input;
}

function playRound(yourSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (yourSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === 3) {
    console.log("you win")
    return true;
  } else if (yourSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === 2) {
    console.log("you win")
    return true;
  } else if (yourSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === 1) {
    console.log("you win")
    return true;
  } else
    console.log("You lose, try again")
  return false;
}

function game() {
  let yourScore = 0,
    computerScore = 0;
  while (true) {
    const yourSelection = playerSelection();
    if (yourSelection === 'exit') break;
    const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
    const youWon = playRound(yourSelection, computerSelection);
    if (youWon) {
      yourScore += 1;
    } else {
      computerScore += 1;
    }
    alert(`${youWon ? 'You won!' : 'Computer won!'} your score=${yourScore}, computerScore=${computerScore}`)
  }
}
game();
```

Answer (score -1):

**It looks like you're off to a good start with your rock-paper-scissors game, but there are some issues in your code that need to be addressed. Here is a corrected version of your code:**

```js
let random;

function getComputerChoice(min = 1, max = 3) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

  if (random === 1) {
    console.log("computer picked Rock");
    return "rock";
  } else if (random === 2) {
    console.log("computer picked Paper");
    return "paper";
  } else {
    console.log("computer picked Scissors");
    return "scissors";
  }
}

function playerSelection() {
  const input = prompt("Input Rock, Paper, or Scissors").toLowerCase();
  console.log("you picked", input);
  return input;
}

function playRound(yourSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (yourSelection === computerSelection) {
    console.log("It's a tie!");
  } else if (
    (yourSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "scissors") ||
    (yourSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper") ||
    (yourSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "rock")
  ) {
    console.log("You win!");
  } else {
    console.log("Computer wins!");
  }
}

function game() {
  let playerScore = 0;
  let computerScore = 0;
  let rounds = 5;

  for (let i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
    const yourSelection = playerSelection();
    const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
    playRound(yourSelection, computerSelection);

    if (yourSelection === computerSelection) {
      // It's a tie; no one scores.
    } else if (
      (yourSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "scissors") ||
      (yourSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper") ||
      (yourSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "rock")
    ) {
      playerScore++;
    } else {
      computerScore++;
    }

    console.log("Player Score: " + playerScore);
    console.log("Computer Score: " + computerScore);
  }

  if (playerScore > computerScore) {
    console.log("You won the game!");
  } else if (playerScore < computerScore) {
    console.log("Computer won the game!");
  } else {
    console.log("It's a tie game!");
  }
}

game();
```

Comment: No, it’s not, this is my answer, not from an AI platform

Comment: im not using AI, I can't lose my whole day with you, -

Comment: Thank u, If you have any concerns or further questions, please feel free to ask, and I'll do my best to help.